# Update Drupal 6 CCK fields through another tool

Tags: 6, entities

I am looking to update the fields of Drupal 6 CCK through a mini panel where some certain users can only change their information.

I am choosing to update out to be an area that customers already know and not have to change environment, in this case Drupal, which is used internally by the team to register a few things.

I found a solution updating directly in the database, but are not advising me, any suggestions for a more correct way?

Comment: My other project was made in CodeIgniter